Does Forcing preserve $\mathsf{DC}$?
As title states, I'm curious whether plain-old Forcing is able to preserve $\mathsf{DC}$ (i.e. whether $\mathsf{DC}$ holds for a generic extension $M[G]$ of some previous model $M$ for which it did hold). From what I know, such a result is well-known with regard to $\mathsf{AC}$ (the answer is "yes"). Having investigated a bit, I found myself upon Asperó & Karagila's paper on the topic, where they mention Monro as having indeed proved that $\mathsf{DC}$ is not always preserved.
From what I've seen, then: $\mathsf{DC}$ is preserved by Proper Forcing, and $\mathsf{AC}_\omega$ is definitely not preserved by regular Forcing. Even though what I mentioned above would seem to indicate that $\mathsf{DC}$ is neither, I'm still a bit dubious as I was tasked by my professor with proving that $\mathsf{DC}$ is indeed preserved by regular-old Forcing. So, what actually is the case here?

You have in hand the paper by Monro, which contains a proof that DC is not preserved by forcing. Have you read the paper? Is there a part of it that you doubt? If you're confused about why your professor is asking your to prove something that contradicts the paper, you should ask your professor for clarification, rather than asking here.

@AlexKruckman Indeed, I do not fully understand the proof by Monro (hence why I'm asking here for definitive confirmation as to its result, given my professor's request). Thus, I would just simply like some confirmation as to whether there are any caveats to Monro's results or it really just proves what it says, and what the corresponding bibliography on Proper Forcing's preservation of $\mathsf{DC}$ might be (as an addendum, of course).

I heard from a lot of colleagues the reaction "Oh, such and such is not so and so without the axiom of choice? I thought it were and told my students that" over the years. I wouldn't be surprised that someone who is not very experienced with forcing in ZF might think that DC cannot be violated by forcing. But the theory of forcing in ZF without AC is actually incredibly fragile compared to the theory in ZFC.

No, of course not. Monro already proved that Dependent Choice is not preserved by generic extensions, as you mentioned.
I worked with Jonathan Schilhan on a related problem, and we wrote a nice paper about this topic, extending Monro's result.

Asaf Karagila and Jonathan Schilhan, Sequential and distributive forcings without choice. Can. Math. Bull. 66 (3), 868-880 (2023) (ZBL07741837, arXiv:2112.14103).

There we define the concept of a "quasiproper forcing" and show that it preserves $\sf DC$, and moreover, if the forcing preserves $\sf DC$ and does not add new $\omega$-sequences to the ground model, it must be quasiproper. But, in general, a $\kappa$-distributive forcing can violate $\sf DC$, even in the presence of $\sf DC_{<\kappa}$.

Thank you so much for your answer and related information! So quasiproper forcing is able to $\mathsf{DC}$, then! (And I assume the result is a weaking of proper forcing's similar ability? What would you say is the general paper/text with a proof with regard to that last point? (I'm trying to build some evidence to present to my professor.)

Sho, all of that (and more!) is in my paper with Jonathan.

Thank you again! (And sorry for the obliviousness.) You were really helpful.
